# Cannot extract Flexray signals from MF4 using dbc file

Tags: python-3.x, asammdf

My question is: Is there a way to extract the flexray singals from Mf4 using dbc/arxml file and save to MDF format

Answer (score 0):

Not until somebody releases a reliable parser for the Fibex and Arxml database formats for Flexray.